# Problem when importing a mesh with Gmsh3D in Fipy

Tags: python, mesh, fipy, gmsh

I am trying to import to Fipy a 3D mesh previously generated with Gmsh using the Gmsh3D function, like this:

```
mesh = Gmsh3D(join(output,'case_1.msh'),communicator=serialComm)
```

I get the same error as other similar posts, but the proposed solutions do not seem to work for me:

```
GmshException: Gmsh hasn't produced any cells! Check your Gmsh code.

Gmsh output:
Info    : Running 'gmsh C:\Users\pcnou\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppouz68km.geo -3 -nopopup -format msh2 -o C:\Users\pcnou\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5es89ie5.msh' [Gmsh 4.6.0, 1 node, max. 1 thread]
Info    : Started on Wed May 05 10:22:49 2021
Info    : Reading 'C:\Users\pcnou\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppouz68km.geo'...
Info    : Done reading 'C:\Users\pcnou\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppouz68km.geo'
Info    : Meshing 1D...
Info    : Done meshing 1D (Wall 0s, CPU 0s)
Info    : Meshing 2D...
Info    : Done meshing 2D (Wall 0s, CPU 0s)
Info    : Meshing 3D...
Info    : Done meshing 3D (Wall 0s, CPU 0s)
Info    : 0 nodes 0 elements
Info    : Writing 'C:\Users\pcnou\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5es89ie5.msh'...
Info    : Done writing 'C:\Users\pcnou\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5es89ie5.msh'
Info    : Stopped on Wed May 05 10:22:49 2021 (From start: Wall 0.00999999s, CPU 0.03125s)
```

I'm working on Win10 with Fipy 3.4.2.1, Python 3.7.9 and Gmsh 4.8.4.

I tried to convert the .msh file into a .msh2 file but then the following error appears:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-38097a945970> in <module>
----> 1 mesh = Gmsh3D(join(output,'case_1.msh2'),communicator=serialComm) # Doesn't work

~\Anaconda3\envs\Ansys\Lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py in __init__(self, arg, communicator, 
overlap, background)
   1991          self.cellGlobalIDs,
   1992          self.gCellGlobalIDs,
-> 1993          self._orderedCellVertexIDs_data) = self.mshFile.read()
   1994 
   1995         self.mshFile.close()

~\Anaconda3\envs\Ansys\Lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py in read(self)
    815             parprint("Recovering coords.")
    816             parprint("numcells %d" % numCellsTotal)
--> 817             vertexCoords, vertIDtoIdx = self._vertexCoordsAndMap(cellsToGmshVerts)
    818 
    819             # translate Gmsh IDs to `vertexCoord` indices

~\Anaconda3\envs\Ansys\Lib\site-packages\fipy\meshes\gmshMesh.py in _vertexCoordsAndMap(self, 
cellsToGmshVerts)
   1008         allVerts     = nx.unique(nx.array(allVerts, dtype=nx.INT_DTYPE)) # remove dups
   1009         allVerts     = nx.sort(allVerts)
-> 1010         maxVertIdx   = allVerts[-1] + 1 # add one to offset zero
   1011         vertGIDtoIdx = nx.ones(maxVertIdx, 'l') * -1 # gmsh ID -> vertexCoords idx
   1012         vertexCoords = nx.empty((len(allVerts), self.coordDimensions))

IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

And the same happens when I use the `.geo` file. Is it a problem of the mesh itself or am I doing something wrong with Gmsh3D? Any help will be highly appreciated.

I first tried with this mesh [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZDT9lr9H51BGU_WXeORDSEJO8oJ2tTj6/view?usp=sharing) that is the one that I expect to work with, but I'm not sure the mesh itself does not have any issues. So I then tried with the following .msh file: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EFjIzve7K0OGagdW33RrmMUEVaODMo0n/view?usp=sharing) and the corresponding .geo file: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wYC80HfQ2RPxwKc9PaoC_V2YEdT89Kdu/view?usp=sharing), but did not work neither.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a link to your `.geo` and `.msh` files

Comment: I first tried with this mesh: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YyN3-e8I3UQRx1VJjXFYNoOo079Ofhq_/view?usp=sharing) but I'm not sure the mesh itself does not have any issues. So I then tried with the following .msh file: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EFjIzve7K0OGagdW33RrmMUEVaODMo0n/view?usp=sharing) and the corresponding .geo file: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wYC80HfQ2RPxwKc9PaoC_V2YEdT89Kdu/view?usp=sharing), but did not work neither.

Comment: OK, thanks. Please edit those links into your question. StackExchange comments are ephemeral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This line of output

  ```
  Info    : Running 'gmsh C:\Users\pcnou\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppouz68km.geo -3 -nopopup -format msh2 -o C:\Users\pcnou\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5es89ie5.msh' [Gmsh 4.6.0, 1 node, max. 1 thread]
  ```

  means that FiPy is interpreting the result of `join(output,'case_1.msh')` as a GEO script, or, more precisely, that it can't find a file in that location, so it assumes that string must be a GEO script. Since it's a file path and not a GEO script, things go south from there.

  I don't know why `join(output,'case_1.msh')` isn't seen as a path to an existing file for you. Is `output` an absolute path or relative? I'd suggest checking against the working directory you launched your script from.
- `case_1_amplazer_pos10001.geo` you provided is not a [Gmsh geometry script](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#Geometry-commands), so neither FiPy nor Gmsh can read it.
- `test.msh` and `case_1.msh` are both version 4.1 MSH files. FiPy cannot read these.
- How did you convert to `MSH2` format?

  I used

  ```
  gmsh -3 -format msh2 case_1.msh -o case_1.msh2
  ```

  and FiPy successfully imported it.

  [image: Mayavi Viewer of FiPy Gmsh3D loaded from test.msh2]

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that converting to `msh2` format with this command line works fine and FiPy imports the meshes without any problem.

Comment: That's great to hear. Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you.